# Commands not working / firing on events built in my customized UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I'm working on this (MVVM) Windows 8.1 metro app where I'm using a `UserControl` that I built separately, this `UserControl` has its own events that I built for it.

My problem is: when I try in the global app to use commands on those they never fires, although the events work!

The `UserControl` and its events :

```
public delegate void PlayClickedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
...
public event PlayClickedEventHandler PlayClicked;
```

The `PlayClicked` event is fired when a button Inside the `UserControl` is clicked

```
private void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (PlayClicked != null)
   PlayClicked(this, e);
}
```

The Global Windows 8.1 MVVM App :

The View :

```
<mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl x:Name="UserControl">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PlayClicked">
              <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnPlayClicked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
```

The ViewModel :

```
public RelayCommand OnPlayClicked { get; set; }
    OnPlayClicked = new RelayCommand(() =>
                                    {
                                       //Stuff to do here that seem not to be done
                                    });
```

Am I missing something ??

Comment: Is this WPF or WinRT? They aren't the same.

Comment: It's a WinRT application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this could explain it (from the docs on [`EventTriggerBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469361.aspx))

> The following events are supported:
>
> (list of 11 events)
>
> Consider implementing a custom behavior to respond to other events.

Why not use an [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.eventtrigger.aspx) instead?  (Also, note that the "OnPlayClicked" binding should really be one way, although this *shouldn't* make a difference.)

```
<mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl x:Name="UserControl">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <uixaml:EventTrigger EventName="PlayClicked">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnPlayClicked}"/>
        </uixaml:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
</mediaPlayerControl:PlayerControl>
```

Comment: Seems that's that, I need to implement my own behavior, thx for Help